# R: delete regular expression in r words in the beginning and end

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Hi I have the following problem, where I am trying to delete the sentences that start with the word QUOTE and end with the word QUOTE. For example:

x=" QUOTEI think I am okayQUOTE I don't think you are"

I want the sentence to look like this:
xx=" I don't think you are"

I have tried the following with gsub but unsucessfully:

```
x= c("QUOTEI think I am okayQUOTE I don't think you are")
xx= gsub("QUOTE*"," ",x)
```

The output of xx unfortunately is "I think I am okayQUOTE I don't think you are".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `gsub("QUOTE.*?QUOTE"," ",x)`

Comment: `stringr::str_remove("QUOTEI think I am okayQUOTE I don't think you are", "QUOTE.*QUOTE")`